# How do I concatenate this string properly?

Tags: php

```
<?php 
    include 'connect.php' ; 

    session_start() ; //basically for all the session data we need 

    $user = $_SESSION['username'] ; 

    $queryFUF = mysql_query("SELECT friends FROM profile WHERE user = '$user'") ;        //query for retrieving the users friends 

    while($arrayFUF = mysql_fetch_array($queryFUF)) {

            $usersFriends = "".$arrayFUF['friends']."" ; //spliting friends out of the array we just got 
    } 

     $strWordCountFriends = str_word_count($usersFriends,1,'_0.9') ;

     foreach($strWordCountFriends as $key => $value) {

        $Ors = 'user = \''.$value.'\' OR ' ;

                echo $Ors;
     } 

echo '<br>';

$mysqlNewsQueryCounstructRaw = 'SELECT user,selfieid,selfieurl,caption,`currenttime`,likes FROM selfiestatusupdates WHERE '.$Ors  ; 

$mysqlNewsQueryCounstructEdited = substr($mysqlNewsQueryCounstructRaw,0,strlen($mysqlNewsQueryCounstructRaw) -3)  ;
echo $mysqlNewsQueryCounstructEdited.'<br>' ;

echo $mysqlNewsQueryCounstructRaw ;
```

the output I get is pretty confusing. This is the output

```
user = 'username' OR user = 'username1' OR 
SELECT user,selfieid,selfieurl,caption,`currenttime`,likes FROM selfiestatusupdates WHERE user = 'username' 
SELECT user,selfieid,selfieurl,caption,`currenttime`,likes FROM selfiestatusupdates WHERE user = 'username' OR
```

Why won't the first part of the variable **$Ors** be displayed when I echo out **$mysqlNewsQueryCounstructEdited**

Comment: Maybe try `$Ors .= ...` instead of `$Ors = ...`

Answer (score 1):

To concatenate a string you need to use `.=`.

So your `$Ors = ...` should be `$Ors .= ...`

```
while($arrayFUF = mysql_fetch_array($queryFUF)) {
    $usersFriends .= "".$arrayFUF['friends']."" ; //spliting friends out of the array we just got 
}
```

And

```
foreach($strWordCountFriends as $key => $value) {
    $Ors .= 'user = \''.$value.'\' OR ' ;
    echo $Ors;
}
```

See [PHP String Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)